# Why does for loop output 0 as the first number and if I write the same for loop condition separately, it will output 1?

Tags: c++

In my opinion, it should output 1 as the first number as variable i is initialized first, then the condition is checked and then it's incremented. When incremented, it should output 1 but it outputs 0 instead. Why?

```
int i = 0; i < 10; ++i;
cout << i;

// Outputs 1
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    cout << i;

// Outputs 0123456789 while having 0 as first number
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int i = 0; i < 10; ++i;
cout << i;
```

This is not a loop. It executes the following things in order:

```
int i = 0;  // sets it to 0
i < 10; // true (result is not stored)
++i; // increments to 1
cout << i;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, the statements are executed separately.

```
int i = 0; i < 10; ++i; // declare variable i, do comparision and discard the result, increment i
cout << i; // print i
```

In the second example, you have to know how `for` works.

[for loop - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)

> ```
> formal syntax:        
> attr(optional) for ( init-statement condition(optional) ; iteration_expression(optional) ) statement
> ```
>
> iteration_expression  -   any expression, which is executed after every iteration of the loop and before re-evaluating condition. Typically, this is the expression that increments the loop counter
>
> The above syntax produces code equivalent to:
>
> ```
> {
>     init_statement
>     while ( condition ) {
>         statement
>         iteration_expression ;
>     } 
> }
> ```

As you see, the iteration_expression `++i` is executed *after* the execution of the loop body, in which `i` is printed. Therefore, the initial value of `i`, which is `0`, is printed in the first iteration.